# Hibernate isn't creating a named tabled in the DB

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a Entity with the name "User". Since Oracle can't create a table with that name, I gave it @Entity(name=) and @Table(name=) properties to ensure it can be created. But still, for some reason the table isn't created. To make matters weirder, all the @JoinTable defined are created correctly, with the according names. Anyone has an idea of what may be causing this?

My class:

```
@Entity(name="USERTABLE")
@Table(name="USERTABLE")
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3895959057511877608L;

private Integer id;
private String name;
private String userName;
private Domain domain;
private String password;
private Boolean mustChangePassword;
private String email;
// 19/07/2012 RP [WEAVER-83]
private Date lastLogin;
private List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="user_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_seq",sequenceName="User_Sequence",allocationSize=1)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(unique = true)
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@ManyToOne
public Domain getDomain() {
    return domain;
}

public void setDomain(Domain domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint")
public Boolean getMustChangePassword() {
    return mustChangePassword;
}

public void setMustChangePassword(Boolean mustChangePassword) {
    this.mustChangePassword = mustChangePassword;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Date getLastLogin() {
    return lastLogin;
}

public void setLastLogin(Date lastLogin) {
    this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id") })
@IndexColumn(name = "listOrder")
public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
    return profiles;
}

public void setProfiles(List<Profile> profiles) {
    this.profiles = profiles;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
@IndexColumn(name = "listOrder")
public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="weaver">
    <jta-data-source>java:/weaverDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
      <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> -->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <!--  http://www.jboss.com/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=78806 -->
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>          
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

UPDATE: I tried creating a naming strategy that adds a prefix at the start of every table, but the table remains uncreated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I didn't noticed the Boolean was set as 'tinyint' (innexistant in OracleSQL) and that the Date can't be normally persisted in OracleSQL (you need to assign a @Temporal=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP for it to do it). Removing the 'tinyint' part and adding the anotation solved it. Moral of the story: always check data types.